# Yahoo Oauth in Ruby API Request - Signature Invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth, yahoo-api

I have already successfully gotten the access token and access secret.  Now I'm trying to make an API request with the OAuth information.

I'm following alongside the yahoo docs (not very helpful): 
https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html
https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html

Also, I'm trying to follow this example closely:
https://gist.github.com/cheenu/1469815

Here is the code: (I split up the long url for convenience)

```
require 'cgi'
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

url = "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/game/nfl"
parameters = "format=json
  &realm=yahooapis.com
  &oauth_consumer_key=#{Rails.application.secrets.yhoo_consumer_key}
  &oauth_nonce=#{SecureRandom.hex}
  &oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
  &oauth_timestamp=#{Time.now.to_i}
  &oauth_token=#{ApiVar.final_oauth_token} #the access token
  &oauth_version=1.0"

base_string = 'GET&' + CGI.escape(url) + '&' + CGI.escape(parameters)

oauth_signature = CGI.escape(Base64.encode64("#{OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', ApiVar.final_oauth_secret + "&", base_string)}").chomp)

#ApiVar.final_oauth_secret is the access token secret - is that what I should be putting there?

testable_url = url + '?' + parameters + '&oauth_signature=' + oauth_signature
p testable_url
response = HTTParty.get(testable_url)
```

My response gives me "signature_invalid."

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    url = "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/{league-key}/players"
    parameters = "format=json&oauth_consumer_key=#{Rails.application.secrets.yhoo_consumer_key}&oauth_nonce=#{SecureRandom.hex}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=#{Time.now.to_i}&oauth_token=#{ApiVar.final_oauth_token}&oauth_version=1.0&realm=yahooapis.com"
    base_string = 'GET&' + CGI.escape(url) + '&' + CGI.escape(parameters)
    secret = "#{Rails.application.secrets.yhoo_consumer_secret}&#{ApiVar.final_oauth_secret}"
    oauth_signature = CGI.escape(Base64.encode64("#{OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', secret, base_string)}").chomp)
    testable_url = url + '?' + parameters + '&oauth_signature=' + oauth_signature
    p testable_url
    response = HTTParty.get(testable_url)

#{Rails.application.secrets.yhoo_consumer_secret}&#{ApiVar.final_oauth_secret}" - correct secret key
```

The parameters have to be ordered alphabetically!   Also, the secret key is the yahoo consumer secret plus the final oauth secret!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I can see as problematic is that the *paremeters* have a lot of whitespace that you do not want.  Try the following instead:

```
parameters = "format=json" +
  "&realm=yahooapis.com" +
  "&oauth_consumer_key=#{Rails.application.secrets.yhoo_consumer_key}" +
  "&oauth_nonce=#{SecureRandom.hex}" +
  "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1" +
  "&oauth_timestamp=#{Time.now.to_i}" +
  "&oauth_token=#{ApiVar.final_oauth_token}" +
  "&oauth_version=1.0"
```

The other issue is that I do not believe your secret key needs the ampersand symbol added to it when you're creating the signature:

```
oauth_signature = CGI.escape(Base64.encode64("#{OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', ApiVar.final_oauth_secret, base_string)}").chomp)
```

Comment: hey Ronen, thanks for answering.  I literally just figured it out an hour ago.  Yeh, the way I displayed it on SO was not how I wrote the actual code - did that just for readability.

Comment: We just collided, so look again at my revised answer.  The ampersand should not be suffixed to your secret key.

Comment: again, thanks so much for your help!  I was using this as a model and it seemed to work https://gist.github.com/cheenu/1469815, although this model leaves out the oauth token in the parameters - something I added and it worked.